# Display the value of product position in category in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2

Looking to display the value of the product position (i.e. sort-by field) via PHTML file.

How would one display the value of that field on the frontend?

Answer (score 4):

In list page,if you have product object then you can find postion by below code

```
$_product->getCatIndexPosition()
```

Comment: How to save product position in category?